# localToGlobal not working - for reals though

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I know there a bajillion threads on this topic, and maybe I am retarded, but this simply isn't working and I think I am missing something really key?

Lets say I have sprites _testTarget and _testParent nested like this.

```
_testParent = new Sprite();
this.addChild(_testParent);

_testTarget = new Sprite()
_testParent.addChild(_testParent);
```

And lets say I want to get the global cords of _testTarget.  When I do localToGlobal I always get back 0,0 when I know for a fact its actual cords are like 200,100

```
var point:Point = new Point(_testTarget.x, _testTarget.y);
    point = _testTarget.localToGlobal(point);  // returns 0,0

var point:Point = new Point(_testTarget.x, _testTarget.y);
    point = _testTarget.parent.localToGlobal(point);  // returns 0,0

var point:Point = new Point(this.x, this.y);
    point = this.localToGlobal(point);  // returns 0,0

var point:Point = new Point(this.x, this.y);
    point = this.parent.localToGlobal(point);  // Breaks, "parent" is null
```

If it helps, this class/sprite instantiated inside of a sprite, inside of a sprite, inside of a sprite...etc and the reason its cords are 200,100 are because one of its parent containers is set to that - but I thought localToGlobal was supposed to go all the way to very top layer?  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, props to all you guys suggesting that I look through the rest of my code because it turns out that yes, I am retarded haha.  On a hunch (from your advise) I found that the problem had nothing to do with localToGlobal - the problem was that I forgot to wait for the stage to be ready.  The solution was very simple:

```
public function ClassConstructorOrWhatever(){
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handleAddedToStage);

    _testParent = new Sprite();
    this.addChild(_testParent);

    _testTarget = new Sprite()
    _testParent.addChild(_testTarget);
}

private function handleAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
    var point:Point = new Point(_testTarget .x, _testTarget .y);
        point = _testTarget.localToGlobal(point); // RETURNS 200,100!!!! :)
}
```

So yeah, that was the problem - thanks again guys!

Answer (score 4):

You must have a problem somewhere else (I can't see anyone in the code you pasted, except for the one mentioned by TandemAdam).

This works as expected:

```
var _testParent:Sprite;
var _testTarget:Sprite;
var _yetAnotherParent:Sprite;

_yetAnotherParent = new Sprite();
this.addChild(_yetAnotherParent);

_testParent = new Sprite();
_yetAnotherParent.addChild(_testParent);

_testTarget = new Sprite()
_testParent.addChild(_testTarget);

_testParent.y = 100;
_yetAnotherParent.y = -500;

var point:Point = new Point(_testTarget.x, _testTarget.y);
    point = _testTarget.parent.localToGlobal(point);  

trace(point); // (x=0, y=-400)
```

As a rule of thumb, when translating between coordinate spaces, the object on which you want to call `localToGlobal` or `globalToLocal` is almost always the parent of the object you're interested in, because an object's x and y are offsets relative to its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah, that's kinda what I figured - I call the parent but it returns null if I try so (which, I admit, is odd).  I guess i'll just take a harder look through the chain of constructors and make sure that everything is init(ed) and ready before I call globalToLocal.  Thanks.

Comment: Your clips need to be added to the stage before using localToGlobal or globalToLocal. If you are creating your clips dynamically, then they wont be on the stage when the constructor is called. You will need to wait for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In your first block, this wont work:

```
_testParent.addChild(_testParent);
```

Because you can't add a display object as its own child.

Comment: sorry, its a type-o (the real app doesn't have that :-p)

Answer (score 0):

This also works as expected -- returns (x=600, y=600). So it looks like there must be something else wrong with your app?

```
var a:Sprite = new Sprite();
var b:Sprite = new Sprite();
var c:Sprite = new Sprite();
var d:Sprite = new Sprite();
var e:Sprite = new Sprite();

a.x = b.x = c.x = d.x = e.x = 100;
a.y = b.y = c.y = d.y = e.y = 100;

this.addChild(a);
a.addChild(b);
b.addChild(c);
c.addChild(d);
d.addChild(e);

var point:Point = new Point(e.x, e.y);

point = e.localToGlobal(point);  

trace(point);
```

Comment: I think the `localToGlobal` line should read `e.parent.localToGlobal(point);`. `e.x` and `e.y` in global coords should be 500,500 in your example, not 600,600. What your code is actually doing is mapping 100,100 *inside* the `e` sprite to global coordinates, which I think is not what you usually want (you want to map e.x and e.y, so you have to call `localToGlobal` on e's parent)